# Are there stealth boy side effects?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Specifically, is The Courier subject to [stealth boy abuse](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Stealth_Boy#Side_effects_2)? I've actually been very hesitant to use stealth boys in New Vegas because of what they did to the nightkin -- and my fear that they might do so to me.

Comment: After reading the article linked (I've not got the game yet... waiting for either a good bit more mods or the GOTY edition, whichever comes first), that would be a bad thing? What am I missing here?

Comment: Schizophrenia and delusions come with being able to turn invisible at will ...

Comment: Oh! That is a good bit of missing I had there. Good to know!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No**, the effects of long-term Stealth Boy abuse, both positive and negative, as seen in the Nightkin will not manifest for the Courier in *Fallout: New Vegas*.

This is confirmed by Doctor Henry in Jacobstown, if asked, he informs the Courier that he has never seen Nightkin-style Stealth-boy-schizophrenia manifest itself in a human.

Comment: This is so confusing to someone who has never played the game... :D

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a definitive answer for New Vegas, but in all the other Fallout games the stealth boys have no negative effects.  Additionally, in terms of gameplay, any "negative" effects they might have will mostly likely be a net positive for a player as they will manifest as a perk.